# how to show the navigation drawer in other activities

Tags: android, material-ui

I have followed this https://youtu.be/VD3YItr9nMg tutorial as it is, but the navigation drawer is only shown in MainActivity. How can I add it in all other activities?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation drawer is used to handle fragments, if you explicitly intent, the layout will be lost, consider using fragments for layout and navigation drawer as fragment host.

For example, try making it via : `File > New > Activity > Navigation Drawer Activity`

It will provide you with templates and fragments.